# Resolving variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Code :

```
$(document).on("click",'#comment-post-btn', function() {alert("yes");   });
```

Here, the id `#comment-post-btn` needs to be replaced by a variable which will finally resolve to  `#comment-post-btn`

How can i do this ?

**Edit:**
I have assigned the id name to a javascript variarble as `var id_name = "#comment-post-btn"`. Now I want to use this variable in place of id name in

```
$(document).on("click",'<idname>', function() {alert("yes"); });
```

Some thing like,

```
$(document).on("click",'id_name', function() {alert("yes"); });
```

Comment: I have assigned the id name to a javascript variarble as var id_name = "#comment-post-btn". Now I want to use this variable in place of id name in $(document).on("click",'<idname>', function() {alert("yes");   });. Some thing like, $(document).on("click",'id_name', function() {alert("yes");   });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var btn_id = 'comment-post-btn';
$(document).on("click",'#' + btn_id , function() {alert("yes"); });
                   //      ^ string concatenation
```

---

if you have `#` already attached for id-selector

```
var btn_id = '#comment-post-btn';
$(document).on("click", btn_id , function() {alert("yes"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like that?

```
var _ButtonID = 1;

$(document).on("click","#Button" +_ButtonID  , function() {alert("yes");   });
```

will result in

```
$(document).on("click","#Button1"  , function() {alert("yes");   });
```